# Recommended system specifications for running ROS2

Tags: gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to buy a new computer and I am wondering what would be the specifications you recommend for a computer to run ROS2 Rolling, Gazebo, RVIZ… as far as I understand  GPU is not that important for running Gazebo, is that correct?

The computer will be for personal development. It won’t be attached to any robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407698/recommended-system-specifications-for-running-ros2/) by [pgarcia-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/116072/pgarcia-dev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2022-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an 8th gen i7 (personal) / 11th gen i7 (work) I use for my every day development, but any modern i5 (or AMD eq.) would be totally sufficient. For years I worked on 6th gen i5 thinkpads and while it lacked some compute on occasion, really anything there and above will be fine.

I'm sure you could get away with much lower if you didn't need to run Gazebo at a reasonable rate. I don't see much difference between 8th gen+ for my normal development, so you could save yourself a few bucks using a couple of generations older CPU models.

Just one data point.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2